# Why `[bezierPath closePath]`method doesn't close my path?

Tags: ios, uiview, uibezierpath, cgpoint

I have an NSArray which contains CGPoints and I draw the path I return from this class. The problem is that  [bezierPath closePath]  doesn't close my path in this class. Why is that? I need to connect the end point to the first point form the array using the curve this class gives me and make the path completely closed/connected and continious using this class. What else should I do apart from `[bezierPath closePath]` because it doesn't do anything when I use this in my drawrect method. Any help is appreciated.

the code for UIBezierPath (SmoothPath) class:

```
UIBezierPath+SmoothPath.h:
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface UIBezierPath (SmoothPath)
+ (UIBezierPath*)smoothPathFromArray:(NSArray*)arr;
@end
```

And

```
  UIBezierPath+SmoothPath.m:

    #import "UIBezierPath+SmoothPath.h"

    @implementation UIBezierPath (SmoothPath)

    + (UIBezierPath*)smoothPathFromArray:(NSArray*)arr{
        if ([arr count] > 0){
            UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

            NSMutableArray *pts = [arr mutableCopy];
            int i = 0;
            for (; i < pts.count - 4 ; i+= 3){
                CGPoint temp = CGPointMake(([pts[i+2] CGPointValue].x + [pts[i+4] CGPointValue].x)/2.0,
                                           ([pts[i+2] CGPointValue].y + [pts[i+4] CGPointValue].y)/2.0);
                pts[i+3] = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:temp];

                [bezierPath moveToPoint:[pts[i] CGPointValue]];
                [bezierPath addCurveToPoint:temp controlPoint1:[pts[i+1] CGPointValue] controlPoint2:[pts[i+2] CGPointValue]];
            }

            switch (pts.count - i) {
                case 4:
                    [bezierPath moveToPoint:[pts[i] CGPointValue]];
                    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint:[pts[i+3] CGPointValue] controlPoint1:[pts[i+1] CGPointValue] controlPoint2:[pts[i+2] CGPointValue]];
                    break;
                case 3:
                    [bezierPath moveToPoint:[pts[i] CGPointValue]];
                    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint:[pts[i+2] CGPointValue] controlPoint1:[pts[i] CGPointValue] controlPoint2:[pts[i+1] CGPointValue]];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    [bezierPath moveToPoint:[pts[i] CGPointValue]];
                    [bezierPath addLineToPoint:[pts[i+1] CGPointValue]];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    [bezierPath addLineToPoint:[pts[i] CGPointValue]];
                    break;

                default:
           }
        [bezierpath closePath];
        return bezierPath;
    }
    return nil;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 4):

You keep moving the path (`moveToPoint`). This makes a discontinuous path so closing it just goes back to the beginning of the last section. When you add a curve or line to a path then the current point of the path is moved to the end of that curve or line. Only use moveToPoint at the beginning, when setting the start point of the path.

Comment: Thank you very much, So I did this `[bezierPath moveToPoint:[pts[0] CGPointValue]];` and brought this line out of the for loop and then used the `[path closePath]` to close the path and it does close the path but still the part between end point and start point ( last index of the array and the first index) is not smooth, How can I make it look continuously smooth even at the joint of the End point and start point?

Comment: You need to calculate a curve as you're doing with the other points. Closing the path will always just do a straight line. Calculate a curve back to the start, add that, then close the path.